# Pressure range conflict between tire and rim

Tags: tire, rims, tubeless, tire-pressure

I just mounted a new Ardnet Race tire that has a side label pressure rating of 35 - 60 psi .  The Stans Arch Ex rim that is mounted to says max pressure is 38 lbs, there is a little range on the sticker depending on the tire size, but this if to the mounted 29" x 2.2" tire.

The suggested ranges says I only have 3 psi to play with, 35-38 psi.  I used to run about 25-28 psi with the former Schwalbe Nobby Nics.  Why is the minimum rated pressure so high on these tires?

Comment: Sounds like a pretty wimpy rim.  Are you sure you're reading the label correctly?

Comment: And what size is that tire?  I don't see any Arch Ex rims listed for 20" tires.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see an answerable question, here. The only people who know _why_ these tyres have the specs they do are Ardnet's design engineers. And how would an answer help you in any practical way?

Comment: "max pressure is 38 lbs" - 38psi?

Comment: Don't mind the rated tire pressure, go by the feel. Unless you weight a ton, I don't see why'd you pump an MTB tire to 38+ psi.

Comment: This link https://www.notubes.com/arch-ex-rims lists "Max Pressure with 2.3” Tire: 38psi".

Comment: Sorry, it is a 29" rim.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - It would help to know if others using these Maxxis Ardent's run with lower than the labeled pressure and have had no issues.

Comment: @Klaster_1 There are at least two problems with underinflated tires: 1. You may feel the tire to start creeping away in tight curves as the sidewall on the inner side of the curve collapses (this has the potential to lead to a crash), and 2. the increased massaging of the sidewalls may speed wear significantly (which may also lead to a crash when the tire explodes). Of course, there should be a significant safety margin in the tire's min inflation rating, so you may get away with inflating to 30psi. But if you do try this, it's 100% your fault if you crash due to either effect.

Comment: I think the question is answerable and should be left open. The question as stated is kind of a design/engineering one, i.e. is there a real reason a dedicated XC race tire would have such a high minimum stated pressure, but that's fine. Certainly the regular Ardent is a tire people run as low as they can get away with. I wouldn't guess the Race version is any different but can't say.

Comment: Thanks all for the replies.  I put out a inquiry with Maxxis support, if they ever reply I'll relay the info.  I'd assume the min pressure rating is for the performance characteristics or the lawyers.

Comment: Pressure ratings on MTB tyres are pretty much nonsense. Conti are very similar with pressures on their XC tyres rated from 35-55psi when in reality everyone runs them between 18-35 psi.  I really don't understand why manufacturers do this - I assume its to cover themselves against the worst case scenario of a very heavy rider cornering aggressively and rolling the tyre off the rim.

Comment: @DanielRHicks If I recall correctly, the low maximum pressure on stans rims is not because they are 'wimpy', its because they use a slightly different bead hook and higher pressures cause the tyre to blow off the rim.

Comment: @GaryBak If you want to know if it's possible to run these tyres with lower pressures, please edit your question to add that -- nobody's going to guess that's what you want without reading through what is now a rather lengthy comment thread.

Comment: Higher pressure should lower rolling resistance, but if it is higher than (narrow ?) rim can stand, you risk rim breaks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Maxxis support is about what I expected.  I am impressed that they responded and withing about a day.

Maxxis Support Team:

> The suggested pressure range is 30-60psi for most applications but you may find 
>   your particular setup to be different. Rim internal width, rider weight, and 
>   riding style determine the correct pressure. I would experiment with different
>   pressures to achieve the tire characteristics that work for you.

I rode the tire at about 28 psi this weekend and it felt good.  Old tire still had tread but was hemorrhaging Stan's from the sidewalls and I could not longer keep up with it.

Comment: So the 30-60psi is a suggested pressure range and not the actual maximum specifications? The Maxxis website lists 60psi as maximum pressure. Theoretically I’d say you can go as low as you want until the sidewalls collapse in turns or you bottom out and get snake bite punctures in your tubes (if you have tubes). The former is the more dangerous of the two, but you have to go quite low or have a pretty narrow rim+wide tire combination.